# Codeigniter Form Validation Rule one field should be bigger then other

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I need to ensure that the `amount` field is bigger than `amount_left` field.

```
$config=array(
    array(
        'field'   => 'amount',
        'label'   => 'actual amount',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required'
    ),
    array(
        'field'   => 'amount_left',
        'label'   => 'amount left',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code:

Create a function:

Hope it will work :

```
function check_bigger($amount,$amount_left)
 {
    if ($amount >= $amount_left)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_bigger', 'The First &amp;/or Second fields have errors.');
        return false;       
    }
    else
   {
        return true;
   }
   }
```

---

```
$v$this->input->post('amount_left');
$config=array(
    array(
        'field'   => 'amount',
        'label'   => 'actual amount',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required|callback_check_bigger['.$v.']',

    ),
    array(
        'field'   => 'amount_left',
        'label'   => 'amount left',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required'
    )
```